# How to make one generic type closely dependent on another in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm looking for a way to make my code more type-safe and would like to define a close relationship between some of my types when passing them to generic functions.

For example, for the given set of types:

```
interface FooParam {}
interface FooReturn {}

interface BarParam {}
interface BarReturn {}
```

and the following function:

```
function action<T, R>(foo: T): R
```

I'd like to closely bind `FooParam` with `FooReturn`, and `BarParam` with `BarReturn`, so the compiler allows the call only if a pair of associated types is passed as `T` and `R` and returns an error otherwise.

```
action<FooParam, FooReturn>(...) // bound types, OK
action<BarParam, BarReturn>(...) // bound types, OK

action<FooParam, BarReturn>(...) // types are not bound, ERROR
action<FooParam, string>(...) // types are not bound, ERROR
```

I've actually managed to achieve the above by defining two base interfaces, which will be later used as constraints on the generic types:

```
interface Param {}
interface Return<T extends Param>{
    _typeGuard?: keyof T
}

interface FooParam extends Param {}
interface FooReturn extends Return<FooParam> {}

interface BarParam extends Param {}
interface BarReturn extends Return<BarParam> {}

function action<T extends Param, R extends Return<T>>(foo: T): R
```

However this seems more like a workaround than a clean solution, especially given the `_typeGuard?: keyof T` field, which exists only so `T` actually matters and is checked, not ignored. Another downside is that every type must extend one of my custom interfaces, which sometimes is just not possible.

Is there a better and more universal way to get the described functionality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a generic type and inference. If your requirements allow this, it could be easier than extending each type from base interface. This solution puts all your links in one place, so it has its own drawbacks, but it seems ok to me if you can't change original types:

```
type Return<T> =
  T extends BarParam ? BarReturn :
  T extends FooParam ? FooReturn :
  never;
```

You can see it in action [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=37&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJygBQ3AtsgbwChlkAjDALmRAFdczoBuEgXyNElkRXSgCUIYWlBCFkJclWQBnMFFABzFuw7ho8JMgBiAe13YoecTH3U6DZsnacNPHfsHDRJs7PlKm1okTABPAAcUJxEQAB4AFQA+ZABeSQjkCAAPSBAAExk0DENjAH5sgSFQ5EoEpNSIDKy9Axx8AtqQlzLSEAgAN2YfGFoQBDBgXTFEQeHIqIAKAPrqCIBKambw6MJJAHp15AARXWQAdwALOEguqGQ-XVoaCAh0gDp7yShilwJWZDgsuBA-FR9NsgABLQFAUIpgZDALIIXRQF4DAA2fmQAAM+MtUURYSA5FIIXFPgMhiBJgR8dQAIwABms8y8QA)

Comment: Great, this seems like something I've been actually looking for, thanks!

Comment: it is a nice one except the thing that it accepts all types. `const barRet1 = action({ unknown: 10 }); ` - doesn't show an error. I would add `function action<T extends BarParam | FooParam>(param: T): Return<T> {`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) than generics.

```js
interface FooParam {
    fooParam: string;
}
interface FooReturn {
    fooReturn: string;
}

interface BarParam {
    barParam: string;
}
interface BarReturn {
    barReturn: string;
}

function action(a: FooParam): FooReturn;
function action(a: BarParam): BarReturn;
function action(a: any): any {
  // implementation, but here you need to solve types first
  // but outside you can't call it like action<FooParam, BarReturn>
}

declare const foo: FooParam;
declare const bar: BarParam;


// you'll get
const fooReturn: FooReturn = action(foo); // bound types, OK
const barReturn: BarReturn = action(bar); // bound types, OK

const test1: BarReturn = action(foo) // types are not bound, ERROR
const test2: string = action(foo) // types are not bound, ERROR
```

I wouldn't suggest to use conditional types in generics here.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the answer! I see that overload would be probably more straightforward therefore more useful in many cases, but I was looking for something universal and independent on the actual number of the pairs. I'd rather avoid having to declare a new method signature and piece of code checking the type in the body every time the project needs a new pair to be added.

Comment: Totally agree, conditional types are good choice to map different types between each other if you need to reuse the mapping in several places, somehow my focus dropped on the `action` function and mapping of its args / returns, in that case I would say overloads fit better. Anyway the question is very good!

Answer (score 0):

I would make coupled interfaces into generics based on linking type:

```
interface Foo {}
interface Bar {}

interface Param<T> {
}

interface Return<T> {
}

interface FooParam extends Param<Foo> {
}

interface FooReturn extends Return<Foo> {
}

interface BarParam extends Param<Bar> {
}

interface BarReturn extends Return<Bar> {
}

function action<T>(foo: Param<T>): Return<T> {
  ...
}
```