# A generic type to describe argument which can be one of few types

Tags: typescript

This question mainly comes from my previous one on this topic: [Declare a custom type for logical argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058187/declare-a-custom-type-for-logical-argument)

Here an example:

```
interface ProductType1 {
  id: string;
}

interface ProductType2 {
  productId: string
}

function getId(product: ???): string {
  return product.id || product.productId || string
}
```

The idea behind this is straight forward: You can pass an object of a type `ProductType1` or `ProductType2` or a product id itself (`string`)

I was trying to do something like:

```
type ProductAsArgument = ProductType1 | ProductType2 | string
```

or

```
interface Product {
  id: string;
  productId: string;
}
```

or

```
interface Product {
  id?: string;
  productId?: string;
}
```

But as you might guess none of this worked since one of the properties never exist on one of the union types (`ProductType1`,`ProductType2`,`string`)

I believe my go-to option is to create some kind of a smart generic that will inherit a `<T>` and will know, that `<T>` can be either on of the types I mentioned above.
I might be wrong here but it looks like to me that generic can solve this issue.

I found some interesting approaches here [How to make one generic type closely dependent on another in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639400/how-to-make-one-generic-type-closely-dependent-on-another-in-typescript) but still don't understand how to apply it on my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is type them

```
interface ProductType1 {
  id: string;
}

interface ProductType2 {
  productId: string
}

function getId(product: ProductType1 | ProductType2 | string): string {
  return (product as ProductType1).id || (product as ProductType2).productId || product as string
}
```

You can also choose to do `typeof product == 'ProductType1'` if statements..

Answer (score 1):

Can you use classes instead of interfaces? In which case you can do something like this, although it would be cleaner to use inheritance for the ProductType classes:

#### Using Classes

```
class ProductType1 {
  id: string = '1';
}

class ProductType2 {
  productId: string = '2';
}

type ProductOrString = ProductType1|ProductType2|string;

function getId(product: ProductOrString): string {
  if (product instanceof ProductType1)
    return product.id;
  else if (product instanceof ProductType2)
    return product.productId;
  else if (typeof product === 'string')
    return product;
  else
    return 'Error in getId(): Unexpected type';
}

let prod1 = new ProductType1();
let prod2 = new ProductType2();
let prod3 = '3';

console.log(`prod1 ID is ${getId(prod1)}`);
console.log(`prod2 ID is ${getId(prod2)}`);
console.log(`prod3 ID is ${getId(prod3)}`);
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAKAnA9gEwK4gC4BUCeADgKYCMsA3sLLAJaoBcsUWiNAdgOawC8sA5CT4BuYAF9goSDAQoM2fMQBMFKrAKzMWAJIMmLdl159FwsRKyEiMtJoDyiAMr7OPa3NyWSAHyQ35lxS9mVk4RYAAzdDZsGmQ2WA4ibVQACnU-LEZfd3snEI4ASkZggxVqGnDYNI1sWjZmCGiiZErszQVSAtVqRCT0RHj09wA6OhFqIjAoKwqqoc06hqaWt3aAruoevoG1Gqxh+ewdcdhJ6dpKlItiFcOsHm4jEs4+Dc3erH7BvZOzom7YB8vvwAKKIFCIOoJJI6FJFWAAVTYRAAHsRsERULBrkRTOJgGAkrs0GReMiAO6rfzEEhwkSE+5DZRkoiUtrUoiKOkEolDADMrj4fNMoDiUGQhOGYGQHBSAAMhmQtAARWhwAAk5ESyWqJIKojlBREIDFEqIUpl8qZsBVatgmu1sKZ+sNxtNkulsoVsgFtpoGq1MNS-JdRuAQA)

Alternatively, using interfaces:

#### Using Interfaces

```
interface ProductType1 {
  id: string;
}

interface ProductType2 {
  productId: string;
}

type ProductOrString = ProductType1|ProductType2|string;

function getId(product: ProductOrString): string {
  if (typeof product === 'string')
    return product;
  else
  if ('id' in product)
    return product.id;
  else if ('productId' in product)
    return product.productId;
  else
    return 'getId(): Unexpected type';
}

let prod1 = { id: '1' };
let prod2 = { productId: '2' };
let prod3 = '3';

console.log(`prod1 ID is ${getId(prod1)}`);
console.log(`prod2 ID is ${getId(prod2)}`);
console.log(`prod3 ID is ${getId(prod3)}`);
```

Comment: I really like both of your answers because of their elegance. I will definitely use some of these approaches when the refactoring time will come :) For now I was looking for something really top-level because at this point I'm just trying to annotate the existing code (as was said in the linked question). Anyways, thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using generics:

```
type Nullish<T> = T|null|undefined;
type ObjOrStr<T> = T|string;

abstract class BaseProduct
{
    id: Nullish<string>;
    productId: Nullish<string>;
}

class Product1 extends BaseProduct
{
    id: string = 'id1';
}

class Product2 extends BaseProduct
{
    productId: string = 'productId2';
}

class SomeClass
{
    getProductId<T extends BaseProduct>(product: ObjOrStr<T>)
    {
        if (typeof product === 'string')
            return product;
        else
            return product.id || product.productId;
    }

    someMethod<T extends BaseProduct>(product: ObjOrStr<T>)
    {
        const productName = this.getProductId(product);

        return productName;
    }
}

let prod1 = new Product1();
let prod2 = new Product2();
let prod3 = 'string3';
let sc = new SomeClass();

console.log(`prod1 id = ${sc.someMethod(prod1)}`);
console.log(`prod2 id = ${sc.someMethod(prod2)}`);
console.log(`prod3 id = ${sc.someMethod(prod3)}`);
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQSwM4AsA8AVAfFAXimwB8A7RBEuMgEwgDNkyJaBuAWAChRIoB5AEYArfgCcAysDE58RbFBJRU05gHNOXbgENBKsdoDGwKIYTbUqKACELEAApiA9rTjHuAb24BIZLQBcsJRoWPrquJreYM6uxgCSAUFIIZhhZGoR3AC+3NxmFlaOLm7AAIxQEAAewBB0VraoDjElnj5+gWlqhFAA5H6lPZo5Wlz5llBFscAATBXVtbT1dpMtXF5cUc3xiZ3dPdHF29OD2bmj5uMSTgC2EADCF6itG2oQwCvbOHM1dTbLW8BcAAKA5TQJCUSSaSyACUPnW3l8DCgQN4ECcyNBJUIBCIPU6PThG0RYjecDEZCgWOMkW8EAQjR8JLJFKpAIAdH5FEpqcB2byEpFhj5UDcIABZN7oFxfKo-RZ-RofQEggHgkTiKQyPBE7wI7yGJxkFRsw7AGDaW7dYDoNDs17vAEJVVmmGaJmk4Dkym8i23IWnEYIN6m2jlIgsADuEwBpSBbu4wZMoNmEYg0eV03jmiToYAzHtOnmTlxc6hDN0o1ArrcHgVs2dDcanMH2QgnGogQADUHlLlEAAkHnL7NFt0lNpcLrDMKyXYToyNotb7c7PZis37UCHI7HEqlU5Ts-nmiby4gbY73dBBa3O8Mo7FE+ltGneePC6AA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to directly answer your question. But for this type of problem

```
You can pass an object of a type ProductType1 or ProductType2 or a product id itself (string).
```

I will have gone in the direction of functions overriding.

```js
function getId(productId: string): string
function getId(product: ProductType1): string
function getId(product: ProductType2): string
function getId(product: string | ProductType1 | ProductType2): string {
  if (typeof product === "string")
    return product;
  else if (product instanceof ProductType1)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is definitely something that should be done in the original code. But as I said in the linked question: I'm working with existing library so changing something inside function is not really my option. Anyways thumbs up!